# Zero partial derivatives and independence of corresponding variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following question which may sound a trivial but it is bothering me a bit since I cannot rigorously explain some moments. Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$ on convex set $G$, then $f$ is independent of variables $y$ and $z$, i.e. $f(x,y,z)=g(x)$ for some function $g$. Let us formalize the question:

More precisely, suppose that $f\in C^1(G;\mathbb{R})$ such that $G\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a convex set and assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\equiv 0$ on $G$.

Using high-dimensional mean value theorem I can show that for any $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in G$ and $(x_0,y_1,z_1)\in G$, we have $$f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=f(x_0,y_1,z_1).$$

But I have difficulties to answer the following questions:

1. How to show that $f(x,y,z)=g(x)$?
2. What is the domain of this $g(x)$?
3. Is $g(x)$ a $C^1$-function also?

I'll highly appreciate if someone would be willing to give me a rigorous answer to my question! Thank you!

Comment: The domain of $g$ would be the projection of $G$ on the $x$-axis. And with geetha290krm's suggestion you can easily see that $g$ is $C^1$ as $f$ and $x\mapsto (x,y_0, z_0)$ are $C^1$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, thank you for your comment! If it is not too difficult you can write it as the answer and I will accept it of course! But what if $f$ is a function of $n$ variables and only $k(k\leq n)$ are equal to zero? What is domain in that case? How do we consider projections here?

Comment: You need to consider all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists $y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,y,z) \in G$. Thus, the possible points are given by $$\{ pr_1(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ (x,y,z) \in G \}$$ where $$ pr_1 : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z) \mapsto x. $$ For higher dimensions, you just project on the relevant variables by the same reasoning.

Comment: Also it might be interesting to note that we do not really need that $G$ is convex. We just need that the fibres of $pr_1: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are connected (we want to show that $f$ is constant on $pr_1^{-1}(\{x\})$ for any given $x$. But $(y,z)\mapsto f(x,y,z)$ has zero derivative and is thus constant if the domain is connected. However, the domain of definition here is exactly the fibre).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, so we define $g:\pi_1(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ as $x\mapsto f(x,y_0,z_0)$. Am I right that here $x_0,y_0$ are not fixed right? I believe that they should depend on $x\in \pi_1(G)$?

Comment: It depends on the shape of $G$ whether we can choose $y_0, z_0$ fixed. We can surely fix them when we are checking for regularity (i.e. locally we could pick them constant). But if you pick $G$ convex and compact, then you can choose $(x_0, y_0, z_0), (x_1, y_1, z_1)\in G$ such that $x_0= \min pr_1(G)$ and $x_1= \max pr_1(G)$. Then we have that $t (x_0, y_0, z_0) + (1-t) (x_1, y_1, z_1) \in G$, this allows you to find $y(x), z(x)$ that are smooth in $x$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Sorry but I think that you misunderstood my question: we have a function $f\in C^1(G;\mathbb{R})$, where $G\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is an open and convex set. Obviously $\pi_1(G):=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y,z)\in G \text{for some} \ (y,z) \}$ is an open set. You suggest to define the function $g:\pi_1(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(x):=f(x,y_0,z_0)$. But what is $(y_0,z_0)$? It could be the case that for some $x\in \pi_1(G)$ the element $(x,y_0,z_0)\notin G$ and in that case $f(x,y_0,z_0)$ is not defined at all.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my previous comment. I am saying that locally we are in the situation where we can fix $y_0,z_0$. That is because you can restrict to a ball, say centered at $(x_0, y_0,z_0)$. Then $(x,y_0,z_0) \in G$. This is all you need to get the regularity argument going. As explained above, if you don't want the reduction to local stuff, you can find functions $y(x), z(x)$ such that $(x,y(x), z(x)) \in G$ and you are good to go too (that was my previous comment).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, what do you mean by regularity argument?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Sorry but I am still confused what is $g(x)$, what is the domain of $g(x)$? How can we have $f(x,y,z)=g(x)$ if the domain of these functions are different (because usually equality of functions mean the equality of their domains also)? I am wondering can you explain this in a separate answer please?

Comment: By regularity argument I mean what I wrote in my first comment. We do not have $f=g$ and nobody claimed this. The domains are different and so they are different functions. All we are saying is that the values of $f$ are determined by the value of the $x$ coordinate only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144571/discussion-between-zfr-and-severin-schraven).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I am wondering we talk in the chat please?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, i am asking because in one theorem which I was trying to understand had the following reasoning: since partial derivative of $f$ wrt to $y$ is zero then in it independent of $y$ and we can write $f(x,y)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we should ask ourself, what should be the domain of $g$? Given that $f$ is defined for all $(x,y,z) \in G$, the domain of $g$ should be

$$ \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \ : \ \exists y,z  \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } (x,y,z)\in G \}.$$

This can be rewritten in terms of the projection map onto the first coordinate. Namely, if $\pi_1: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z) \mapsto x$, then the domain of $g$ should be $\pi_1(G)$.

We can define

$$ g: \pi_1(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad  g(x) = \inf_{(x,y,z) \in \pi_1^{-1}(\{x\})} f(x,y,z). $$

In fact, for $(x,y,z), (x, \tilde{y}, \tilde{z}) \in \pi_1^{-1}(\{x\})$ we have

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) - f(x,\tilde{y}, \tilde{z}) &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(x, y+t(\tilde{y}-y), z + t(\tilde{z}-z)) dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[ \partial_2 f\big(x, y+t(\tilde{y}-y), z + t(\tilde{z}-z)\big)  \cdot (\tilde{y}-y) + \partial_3 f\big(x, y+t(\tilde{y}-y), z + t(\tilde{z}-z)) \cdot (\tilde{z}-z)\big) \right] dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[0\cdot (\tilde{y}-y) + 0\cdot (\tilde{z}-z)\right] dt =0.
\end{align*}
Here we used that $\partial_2 f= 0 = \partial_3 f$ and the fact that $G$ is convex such that the line connecting $(x,y,z)$ and $(x,\tilde{y}, \tilde{z})$ is fully contained in $G$. As you noted yourself, you could also use the mean value theorem, I just wanted to give a possible different variation. So at the end of the day, we got that $f(x,y,z)$ is constant on $\pi_1^{-1}(\{x\})$ and thus, $g$ is actually well-defined (a priori it would be possible that the infimum is $-\infty$).

Next, we will show that $g$ is actually $C^1(\pi_1(G))$. Regularity is a local question, thus, it is enough to consider an arbitrary cube $Q\subseteq G$ centered at some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and show that $g$ is $C^1$ in $Q$. Because the cube is fully contained in $G$ (here I am assuming that $G$ is open, which you mentioned in the comments is what you want), we get that for all $x\in \pi_1(Q)$ we have $(x,y_0, z_0)\in Q$. Thus, for $(x,y,z) \in Q$ we can write

$$ f(x,y,z)= g(x) = f(x,y_0,z_0). $$

Hence, we can write $g$ as the composition of the $C^1$ maps $f$ and $x\mapsto (x, y_0, z_0)$.

In higher dimensions, everything works the same. If you wish $g$ to depend on more variables, just consider the appropriate projections to more variables.

Comment: It makes more sense but I am still confused when you are trying to show that $g$ is  $C^1$ function. First of all, $g:\pi_1(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ and we need to show that $g\in C^1(\pi_1(G);\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I am puzzled by your comment. You are the one that wants to show that $g$ is $C^1$ (that isyourthird point). And that is what I did.

Comment: Also, it is in general quite rude to edit posts just to change notation. I do not like to call projections $\pi_1$.

Comment: What exactly confuses you in my proof?